# Unexpected need for a server side proof of life to maintain or open an xrdp session if running Gnome?

Tags: debian, gnome, xrdp

I installed Xrdp on a Debian-12.5.0-amd64
with the Gnome windows manager:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install xrdp
systemctl status xrdp
sudo adduser xrdp ssl-cert
systemctl restart xrdp
```

/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini is configured as such:

```
[Sessions]
...
KillDisconnected=false
DiconnectedTimeLimit=0
IdleTimeLimit=0
```

I can connect using windows remote desktop and it works well,
but the session freeze and then disconnect after a few minutes of inactivitiy saying that the session is over.

I need to type on the server keyboard for the client to be able again to join the remaining session.

- How to maintain the ability to open xrdp session without timeout ?
- how to work with a remote headless server, not requiring a local proof of life ?

Regards.

Note that if using Xfce instead of Gnome,
or if using Gnome on Ubunutu instead of Debian,
the problem does not occur !

Answer (score 0):

The solution I could test successfully is to disable sleep, suspend and hibernation using the following command:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

To re-enable sleep, suspend and hibernation, use the following command:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

Solution found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529524/158686)